# Convicted on/of a misdemeanor

Tags: prepositions

> He was convicted **on/of** a misdemeanor.

I am confused in this sentence, I know the commoner phrase is “convicted of”, but I have recently read some examples where “convicted on” is used. How to differentiate between these two? Can we use both the prepositions in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition **of** is much more common than **on** in that use.

Here is a frequency comparison:
[Google Ngram Viewer "convicted on/of a misdemeanor"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=convicted%20on%20a%20misdemeanor%2C%20convicted%20of%20a%20misdemeanor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20on%20a%20misdemeanor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20of%20a%20misdemeanor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20on%20a%20misdemeanor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20of%20a%20misdemeanor%3B%2Cc0)

However, "convicted on a misdemeanor charge", where the word "misdemeanor" is an adjective, is another matter, because "convicted **on** a charge [**of** some crime]" is much more common than "convicted of a charge".

[Google Ngram Viewer "convicted on/of a charge"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=convicted%20on%20a%20charge%2C%20convicted%20of%20a%20charge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20on%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconvicted%20of%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you! Should I use “a misdemeanor charge” instead of “a misdemeanor”? Is it okay to use “a misdemeanor” only?

Comment: Yes, either one is alright.